# Python ElementTree XML Parsing: element objects's bool value is strange

Tags: python, xml

my `xml` file like this:

```
<aiml>
<category>
    <pattern>*test*</pattern>
    <template><srai>test</srai></template>
</category>
</aiml>
```

The trouble is when I check `srai`'s bool value, it returns false

```
(Pdb) not srai_tag
True
(Pdb) srai_tag
<Element 'srai' at 0x10e08fea8>
(Pdb) not template
False
(Pdb) template
<Element 'template' at 0x10e08fe58>
```

My python version is 3.6.1.

Comment: Classes are free to define True/False however they wish.   Do you know how the `Element` class defines it?

Comment: Oh, They will change the `__bool__` method in future versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the class `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`, they will change it in future. Thanks for [John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon)'s remind.

```
def __bool__(self):
    warnings.warn(
        "The behavior of this method will change in future versions.  "
        "Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.",
        FutureWarning, stacklevel=2
        )
    return len(self._children) != 0 # emulate old behaviour, for now
```